# Publishing post with pictures without album, using facebook graph api

Tags: javascript, facebook, image, facebook-graph-api, feed

I want to publish posts with uploaded pictures to wall of user/page/group directly without adding it in an album. How do I achieve it?

**This is how I do it right now:**

1. Finding album, of creating if it's not yet existed;
2. Uploading image to this album;
3. Publishing post. This post contains *message* and *link* fields. *Link* field contains url to photo that was uploaded in second step. For publishing post, I use an **{id}/feed** method.

That way works, but It's not quite what I want. I want to publish it directly to wall without album, because sometimes there are will create new posts, that contains photos, that recently have been added to album. Also using this way I can attach only one photo in link field, but I want to sent more then one.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `/me/photos` as the endpoint to publish. This will publish the photo to the timeline.

Comment: This method accepts list of photos and paging object. `{
    "data": [],
    "paging": {}
}`
But I want to publish **text** with photos.

Comment: @Mike_Device the documentation is incomplete. If you know how to do this "Uploading image to this album" then just switch `albumid/photos` for `me/photos` using the `source` and `message` fields.